# Rendering a Heterogeneous Collection of View Models in Silverlight 2

Tags: collections, silverlight-3.0, mvvm, silverlight-2.0, heterogeneous

I have a hierarchy of view models representing formatted content:

```
public abstract class ContentPartViewModel : ViewModel
{
}

public class TextContentPartViewModel : ContentPartViewModel
{
    public string Text { ... }
}

public class TitleContentPartViewModel : TextContentPartViewModel
{
}

public class HyperlinkContentPartViewModel : TextContentPartViewModel
{
    public string Uri { ... }
}
```

I have an encompassing view model that contains a collection of `ContentPartViewModel`s to be rendered:

```
public class ContentViewModel
{
    public ICollection<ContentPartViewModel> ContentParts { ... }
}
```

I then have a `ContentView` that renders all parts of the content:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ContentParts}"/>
</UserControl>
```

In an ideal world, I would just define a `DataTemplate` for each of the content part types and they would be rendered accordingly. However, Silverlight does not support the `DataType` property on the `DataTemplate` class, so that is not an option.

Another option would be to provide a `DataTemplateSelector` and do the mapping from view model type to `DataTemplate` myself. Alas, `ItemsControl` in SL2 does not have an `ItemTemplateSelector` property - only an `ItemTemplate` property.

That left me with no option but to provide an `ItemTemplate` that then uses a converter to turn off all the UI apart from the piece relevant to that content part:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TitleContentPartConverter}}"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextContentPartConverter}}"/>

            <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Text}" NavigateUri="{Binding Uri}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource HyperlinkContentPartConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This is obviously rather awful, both for performance and for readability/correctness of code. It also makes it much harder for me to format the output correctly. So, questions:

1. Can anyone recommend a better way to do this in SL2?
2. Can anyone confirm whether the situation has improved in SL3?

Thanks,
Kent

Comment: if it makes you feel better, the 'View' in ModelView actually explains the presence of visibility stuff in your Bindings. I do however feel your pain (and wait for SL5 too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. DataType in DataTemplate is not supported in Silverlight 2 or Silverlight 3.
2. You can work around ItemTemplateSelector in Silverlight. Please take a look at this sample.

http://silverlight.net/forums/t/12598.aspx

```
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
{
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item); 
    DataTemplateSelector selector = this.ItemTemplateSelector;

    if (null != selector)
    {
        ((ContentPresenter)element).ContentTemplate = selector.SelectTemplate(item, element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Not ideal that I have to create all that infrastructure and subclass various ItemsControls myself, but seems like it should work. Will update once I've tried it.

Comment: The sample nor this question isn't really complete w/o this link too: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/79266.aspx That shows you how to define the DataTemplate resources and reference them programmatically.